# Python Pandas sort by Time and group by user ID

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I am loading a CSV file with pandas. It has three columns: a column with date and time, a column with a user id, and another 'campaignID'. 
Example rows:

```
date                 user_id              campaign_id
2018-01-10 0:21:09   151312395            GOOGLE
2018-01-10 0:21:19   151312395            GOOGLE
2018-01-10 0:21:32   151312395            GOOGLE
```

I want to group the data by the user id, and then for each user id group the rows by time and the campaign ID, it should look as follows.

```
user_id              date                           ad_campaign
151312395            2018-01-10 0:21:09             GOOGLE
                     2018-01-10 0:21:19             GOOGLE
                     2018-01-10 0:21:32             GOOGLE
```

This is what I have made until now:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime

```
def dateparse(time_in_secs):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
columnnames = ['date','user_id', 'ad_campaign']
columnnames, sep='\t' ,usecols=[0,1,3],index_col = 'date')
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\L\Desktop\Data.csv' , 
     sep='\t',names = columnnames, usecols=[0,1,3], 
    parse_dates=True,date_parser=dateparse)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.sort_values(by = 'date')
g = df.groupby('user_id')['ad_campaign']
print(g)
```

This gives the following output:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x04EF26F0>
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

Why doesnt the print provide the sorted columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you are doing `groupby`, you don't need to sort the column explicitly.

You can do:

**Method 1:**

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
g = df.groupby(['user_id','date'])['ad_campaign']
print(g.first())
```

**Method 2:**

```
df.set_index(['user_id','date']).sort_index()
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm allowed to ask a follow up question here, but even though it works I am stuck at my following step..

Comment: @LailaVanMents I don't know either, but if it's the same question you can ask. What's that?

Comment: Made a new question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099105/dynamic-location-count-in-pandas-array

Answer (score 1):

You could try `df.set_index(['user_id', 'date'])`.